# Applying lognormal distribution to my data using glm function in R

Tags: r, modeling, glm, lme4

I want to implement a mixed effects model on my data with a specific type of distribution. Here is an example of my data named "a":

```
dput(head(a))

structure(list(pNum = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FirstSteeringTime = c(0.433389999999999, 
0.449999999999989, 0.383199999999988, 0.499899999999997, 0.566800000000001, 
0.58329999999998), error_rate = c(2.86537083478438, 11.459301348013, 
2.86537083478438, 3.82015500141104, 2.86537083478438, 3.82015500141104
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

First I see what distribution best suits my data:

```
# gamma distribution
fit_g  <- fitdist(magnitudedata$FirstSteeringTime, "gamma")

# log normal distribution - can only be used on positive values (any zeros and it will fail)
fit_ln <- fitdist(magnitudedata$FirstSteeringTime, "lnorm")

# weibull distribution
fit_w <- fitdist(magnitudedata$FirstSteeringTime, "weibull")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot.legend <- c("Weibull", "gamma", "lognormal")
denscomp(list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
cdfcomp (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp  (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
ppcomp  (list(fit_w, fit_g, fit_ln), legendtext = plot.legend)
```

From these plots, it appears that gamma and lognormal distributions are most related to my data.

[image: Distribution plots]

I can fit the gamma distribution by using the glmer function from the lme4 package and specifying the family as "Gamma"

```
# model 3 - applying gamma distribution
m3 <- glmer(FirstSteeringTime ~ error_rate + (1 + error_rate | pNum), family = Gamma, data = a)
```

However I'm unsure how to specify a lognormal distribution. I have looked at the documentation for these functions and packages, and I cannot simply specify that "lognormal" is the family.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can implement my mixed effects model with a lognormal distribution? Any help is appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21447/how-to-specify-a-lognormal-distribution-in-the-glm-family-argument-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for this!